# Hibernate: is there any way save object with utf-8 characters to table in latin1 encoding?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, encoding

currently my spring application is connecting to mysql database with characterEncoding=UTF-8 connection, but several tables have encoding in latin1, really I don't need utf-8 characters be stored to dabase as original, for me saving '?????' instead of them is acceptable, but now I'm getting this error:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\xD1\x84\xD1\x8B\xD0\xB2...' for colum
```

Is there any way save question marks for given tables instead of throwing error? (converting table to utf-8 is not acceptable way for my situation)

Comment: now all connection in application are managing by spring data, change it to manually management don't look for me an easy solution

Answer (score 0):

You could either `replaceAll` non-latin1 characters with `'?'` using

```
value.replaceAll("[^\x0-\x7f]", "?")
```

Or you could probably simply encode and re-decode using `StandardCharsets.US_ASCII`.